# Une phrase à la forme négative peut-elle rester une affirmation?

Tags: négation, terminologie

1. Il est chauve.
2. Il n'a pas un cheveu sur la tête.

La première phrase est une affirmation.
Quelle est le mot qui se rapporterait à la seconde?
Une *négation* ne convient pas. Une affirmation négative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Les deux sont pour moi des affirmations, « actions (ou résultats de l'action) de dire nettement qu'une chose existe ou n'existe pas » en prenant la définition qui me semble la plus pertinente du TLFi.

La deuxième prend effectivement la forme d'une litote.

Qu'elles soient — et toutes deux peuvent l'être — des infirmations ou des dénégations dépend d'un contexte dont nous ne disposons pas.

Answer (score 3):

Si tu cherches simplement des antonymes d'*affirmation*, le CNRTL en propose [quelques-uns](http://www.cnrtl.fr/antonymie/affirmation), dont *démenti* ou *contestation*, mais rien de très convaincant (*négation* y est repris aussi, et d'après sa [définition](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/n%C3%A9gation) il ne convient pas si mal, il est d'ailleurs mentionné aussi dans celle d'*[affirmation](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/affirmation)*).

Pour moi, le plus simple reste l'*infirmation* , voire la *dénégation*.

Sinon, il y a aussi la [litote](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/fr/wiki/Litote), figure de style consistant à nier l'inverse de ce qu'on veut dire pour en renforcer le sens (*Il ne fait pas chaud* pour dire qu'il fait froid) — mais je ne pense pas que ce soit ce que tu cherches.

Comment: *dénégation* ne convient pas du tout.

Comment: Lequel préfères-tu, en fait ?

Comment: Je dirais avec le mot, donc au masculin (surtout si _négation_ était entre guillemets ou en italique), mais franchement ça mérite sa propre [question](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).

Comment: Dans mon exemple litote semble être la réponse à ma première question secondaire. Par contre je n'ai jamais entendu négation utilisée de cette manière. En passant avec quoi dois-je accorder utilisé? Le mot négation (masculin)? ou une négation (féminin)? En gros lequel des 2 est sous-entendu?